# can not create database from entity class

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, netbeans

I can't create the database although I have included the persistence unit in ejb project. Is any one have an idea of what's going on here?
I have included my code here
 Car class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CARS")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Cars.findAllCar, query = "SELECT c FROM Cars c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cars.findByVinNo", query = "SELECT c FROM Cars c WHERE c.vinNo = :vinNo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cars.findByModelNo", query = "SELECT c FROM Cars c WHERE c.modelNo = :modelNo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cars.findByModelName", query = "SELECT c FROM Cars c WHERE c.modelName = :modelName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cars.findByManufacturer", query = "SELECT c FROM Cars c WHERE c.manufacturer = :manufacturer"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cars.findByCarType", query = "SELECT c FROM Cars c WHERE c.carType = :carType"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cars.findByCarDescrip", query = "SELECT c FROM Cars c WHERE c.carDescrip = :carDescrip"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cars.findByCarUrl", query = "SELECT c FROM Cars c WHERE c.carUrl = :carUrl")})
public class Cars implements Serializable {
    public static final String findAllCar = "Cars.getAll";

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "VIN_NO")
    private String vinNo;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "MODEL_NO")
    private String modelNo;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "MODEL_NAME")
    private String modelName;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "MANUFACTURER")
    private String manufacturer;
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "CAR_TYPE")
    private String carType;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "CAR_THUMBNAIL")
    private Serializable carThumbnail;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "CAR_DESCRIP")
    private String carDescrip;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "CAR_URL")
    private String carUrl;

    public Cars() {
    }

    public Cars(String vinNo) {
        this.vinNo = vinNo;
    }

    public String getVinNo() {
        return vinNo;
    }

    public void setVinNo(String vinNo) {
        this.vinNo = vinNo;
    }

    public String getModelNo() {
        return modelNo;
    }

    public void setModelNo(String modelNo) {
        this.modelNo = modelNo;
    }

    public String getModelName() {
        return modelName;
    }

    public void setModelName(String modelName) {
        this.modelName = modelName;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getCarType() {
        return carType;
    }

    public void setCarType(String carType) {
        this.carType = carType;
    }

    public Serializable getCarThumbnail() {
        return carThumbnail;
    }

    public void setCarThumbnail(Serializable carThumbnail) {
        this.carThumbnail = carThumbnail;
    }

    public String getCarDescrip() {
        return carDescrip;
    }

    public void setCarDescrip(String carDescrip) {
        this.carDescrip = carDescrip;
    }

    public String getCarUrl() {
        return carUrl;
    }

    public void setCarUrl(String carUrl) {
        this.carUrl = carUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (vinNo != null ? vinNo.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Cars)) {
            return false;
        }
        Cars other = (Cars) object;
        if ((this.vinNo == null && other.vinNo != null) || (this.vinNo != null && !this.vinNo.equals(other.vinNo))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "fit5042.entities.Cars[ vinNo=" + vinNo + " ]";
    }

}
```

Customer class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = Customer.GET_ALL_QUERY_NAME, query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c")})
public class Customer implements Serializable{

    public static final String GET_ALL_QUERY_NAME = "Customer.getAll";

    private int id;
    private String surname;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String type;
    private String address;
    private String tel;
    private Set<Orders> order;
    //private Set<Cars> car;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(int id,String surname, String name, String email,
            String password, String type, String address, String tel, Orders orders) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.type = type;
        this.address = address;
        this.tel = tel;
        this.order = new HashSet<>();
        //this.car = new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "customer_surName")
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @Column(name = "customer_name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "customer_email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name = "customer_passwd")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "type")
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Column(name = "customer_address")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Column(name = "customer_tel")
    public String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public void setTel(String tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }



    /*@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    public Set<Cars> getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(Set<Cars> car) {
        this.car = car;
    }*/

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    public Set<Orders> getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Set<Orders> order) {
        this.order = order;
    }




}
```

Salesperson class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SALESPERSON")
public class SalesPerson {
    public static final String GET_ALL_QUERY_NAME = "Customer.getAll";

    private int id;
    private String surname;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String type;
    private String address;
    private String tel;
    private Set<Orders> order;

    public SalesPerson() {
    }

    public SalesPerson(int id,String surname, String name, String email,
            String password, String type, String address, String tel, Orders orders) {
        this.id = id;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.type = type;
        this.address = address;
        this.tel = tel;
        this.order = new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "sales_id")
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "sales_surName")
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @Column(name = "sales_name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "sales_email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name = "sales_passwd")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "type")
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Column(name = "sales_address")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Column(name = "sales_tel")
    public String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public void setTel(String tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "salesperson")
    public Set<Orders> getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Set<Orders> order) {
        this.order = order;
    }




}
```

Order class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDERS")
public class Orders implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Order_id")
    private int order_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sales_id")
    private SalesPerson salesPerson;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "orders")
    private Cars car;

    public Orders(int order_id, Customer customer, SalesPerson salesPerson, Cars car) {
        this.order_id = order_id;
        this.customer = customer;
        this.salesPerson = salesPerson;
        this.car = car;
    }

    public int getOrder_id() {
        return order_id;
    }

    public void setOrder_id(int order_id) {
        this.order_id = order_id;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public SalesPerson getSalesPerson() {
        return salesPerson;
    }

    public void setSalesPerson(SalesPerson salesPerson) {
        this.salesPerson = salesPerson;
    }

    public Cars getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(Cars car) {
        this.car = car;
    }



}
```

The relationship between the four tables should be: customer and saleperson will having a one to many relationship with orders. orders will have a one to one relationship with car.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I use netbeans. Just run the application and nothing happened with the jdbc database.

Comment: show your persistence unit details then.  Did you set up DDL generation?  Are you telling netbeans to create the database for you?